# Simple memory allocation for embedded application

Tags: c

I need to have dynamic memory allocation without the use of malloc in an embedded application.
As we have enough RAM, I would like to allocate a big array (A[A_MAX]) on startup and have buffer arrays (B[]) within this one big array.
They would always begin at A[0] and be as long as they need (at max A_MAX, but mostly shorter).

Example:
at start up:

```
A[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

declaring B[4] at A[0] and filling B with ones

```
B[4] = {1,1,1,1};
```

now A should look like this:

```
A[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}
```

How can I do this?

I looked at the sourcecode for malloc() and it does return the address of the next free part of the heap.
but when I use

```
float *B[4] = &A[0];
```

my compiler returns an error (invalid initializer)

Comment: Just use an union.

Comment: Do you need the sub-identifier to be an array? Can't you use pointers and initialize them with pointers to main array elements?

Comment: What datatype did you use for A[]?

Comment: @KamilCuk I will look into that

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh would it work just like a normal Array?

Comment: @neon tha same as B (float)

Comment: @JohannesHaßler not really, but in most of the cases, you can manage using a pointer instead of an array. Do you have any specific use-case that needs the input to be array type?

Comment: So in your last example you try to put a pointer to A[0] into an array of float-pointers at index 4. This would explain your `invalid initializer` error.

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, I have library functions that need an array as an input and output.
They can have different sizes, but instead of reserving memory from the start for all individual cases or using malloc() as is, I want to use the same memory space again and again.

Comment: @neon I use malloc() like this `float *B = malloc(sizeof(float) * nSamples)`,  but thought I needed to write the length of the Array.

Now I wrote it like this `float *B = &A[0]` and it worked!
Now I get A[8] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @neon mentioned I wanted to write an address to a float array.

Writing it like `float *B = A[0]` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#define A_MAX  8
alignas(max_align_t) char _memory[A_MAX] = {0};
```

*then* you can just use pointers:

```
int main() { 
     {
         float *floatdata = (void*)_memory;
         // use floatdata
     }
     {
         int *intdata = (void*)_memory;
         // use intdata
     }
}
```

I would write a handy function to calculate the maximum size for error checking:

```
// query the max size and allocate
inline void *dataalloc(size_t elemsize, size_t *n) {
    *n = sizeof(_data) / elemsize;
    return _data;
}
```

and do:

```
size_t size;
float *floatdata = dataalloc(sizeof(*floatdata), &size);
// use as-if floatdata[size]
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) floatdata[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like ? I'm using pointers to the array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void allocator(float* src,int SrcSize,float **dst,int size,int pos){
    if(size <= SrcSize)
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        dst[i] = &(src+pos)[i];
    }
}


int main()
{
    float A[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    float *B[4];
    float *C[4];
    allocator(A,sizeof(A)/sizeof(float),B,4,0);
    *B[2] = 4;
    allocator(A,sizeof(A)/sizeof(float),C,4,4);
    *C[0] = 6;
    printf("A[2] value is : %f\n" , A[2]); // output is 4.000 
    printf("A[4] value is : %f\n" , A[4]); // output is 6.000

    return 0;
}
```